# Spark job cannot delete its temporary folders at the end

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-data-lake, azure-hdinsight

I have got a spark job running in Azure HDInsight which does some transformation on data (which resides in ADLS) and in the end writes the partitioned data back to the Azure Data lake Store. While processing the spark job create a folder with many subfolders called "_temporary", I guess for meanwhile calculation results. In the end the spark job deletes this temp folder. And in some cases this deletion fails.

When it fails there is coming the following exception:

```
 

    ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null.
    com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLException: Error deleting directory tree /data/datalake/processed/raw/_temporary
    Operation DELETE failed with exception java.net.SocketTimeoutException : Read timed out
    Last encountered exception thrown after 5 tries. [java.net.SocketTimeoutException,java.net.SocketTimeoutException,java.net.SocketTimeoutException,java.net.SocketTimeoutException,java.net.SocketTimeoutException]
     [ServerRequestId:null]
        at com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLStoreClient.getExceptionFromResponse(ADLStoreClient.java:1194)
        at com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLStoreClient.deleteRecursive(ADLStoreClient.java:614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.AdlFileSystem.delete(AdlFileSystem.java:574)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.cleanupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:510)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:403)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:364)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:47)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:154)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225)
        at com.bosch.ic.spark.dataprocessor.DataProcessor.transformParquetContent(DataProcessor.scala:53)
        at com.bosch.ic.spark.dataprocessor.Application$.main(Application.scala:15)
        at com.bosch.ic.spark.dataprocessor.Application.main(Application.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$4.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:721)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at org.wildfly.openssl.OpenSSLSocket.read(OpenSSLSocket.java:423)
        at org.wildfly.openssl.OpenSSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLInputStream.java:41)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1587)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
        at com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.HttpTransport.makeSingleCall(HttpTransport.java:307)
        at com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.HttpTransport.makeCall(HttpTransport.java:90)
        at com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.Core.delete(Core.java:311)
        at com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLStoreClient.deleteRecursive(ADLStoreClient.java:612)
        ... 34 more
```

So it seems like the internally used ADL Client fails to delete the temp folder by a socket timeout exception.

This happens sometimes but not in all cases..did somebody encounter the same problem?

Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved. The problem was on Azure side. Due to high network traffic within Azure the communication between the services had problems.